# Cancel Button shows required error

Tags: liferay, liferay-aui

I have a form with input having validator and also autoFocus (required), submit button and cancel button. When I click on cancel button it shows required error and then redirect to another page.

What I want is : How could I prevent form validation when I click on Cancel Button.

When removing the autoFocus it works but I can't remove it.

P.S : I'm using liferay 6.2 with Alloey

CODE JSP :

```
<portlet:renderURL var="cancelURL">
    <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/html/view.jsp" />
</portlet:renderURL>
<aui:button href="<%=cancelURL %>" name="cancelButton" id="cancelButton" value="Cancel"></aui:button>
```

Comment: What is the type of cancel button? Can you share the relevant code?

Comment: I've included the code above

Comment: Set `type="button"` on `aui:button` to make just button, as this attribute defaults to`submit`

Comment: Also, don't set `href` attribute, just invoke javascript on click event as `onclick="window.location.href = '<%=cancelURL %>'";`

Comment: I did as you told me but nothing has changed, and for onclick event I have a form with onclick event so it is the same. When i disable the autofocus it does not show the required error but I need the autofocus

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK validation fires when the input element looses focus - which is what happens when you click the cancel button. This would happen with or without autofocus, if the input already has the focus (automatically or manually shouldn't mapper) The only workaround that I can think of is to change the cancel button to remove any validation complaint (as they'll already have been set) before doing its regular business.

Note that this is also a problem with accessibility: If you navigate to the cancel button by pushing `<tab>`, you'll essentially trigger every single input element's validation that you intermittently have focus in. Upon loosing focus you probably don't know where focus goes to, so you can't do a lot then. Only once you know that "Cancel" has been clicked you can act. Note that you can't even act "onFocus" for the cancel button: It might have been focussed just by keyboard-navigation, before continuing to the "ok" button and submission.  (Does this last sentence make sense to you or should I rephrase it?)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes it makes sence. How about changing focus or something on blur event ?